# Why is my React code rendering multiple elements when I return data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to building a React app that returns information about congress when you type in a state in the search box. The only problem is that when it renders, the same information renders multiple times. I know that that when an element renders it will share the same class and it's styling but this is something that I don't know how to fix, as I am new to React. Can some point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
class Members extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: null,
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: []
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const urls = [`https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/102/house/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/latest.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/search.json`];

    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url, {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'X-API-Key': key
      }
    }))
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(res => {
        return Promise.all(res.map(res => res.json()));
      }).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          senators: response[0].results[0].members,
          represenatives: response[1].results[0].members,
          bills: response[2].results
        })
        console.log(this.state.senators)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

  render() {

    const { senators, bills, represenatives, userInput } = this.state;

    const inSenate = senators.filter(
      (senator) => senator.state === userInput
    )

    const inHouse = represenatives.filter(
      (represenative) => represenative.state === userInput
    )

    const draft = bills.find(
      (bill) => bill.name === inSenate.last_name)


    return (
      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        {inSenate.map((senate, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={inSenate.id} className="senate">
              <h2 key={inSenate.id} className="senateName">Senate</h2>
              <ul key={inSenate.id} className="bio">
                <h2 key={inSenate.id}>{senate.short_title + " " + senate.first_name + " " + senate.last_name}</h2>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>{senate.title}</li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>State: <strong>{senate.state}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>Party: <strong>{senate.party}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>DOB: <strong>{senate.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>Next Election: <strong>{senate.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>Missed Votes: <strong>{senate.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}> Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li key={inSenate.id}>Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        {inHouse.map((rep, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={inHouse.id} className="houses">
              <h2 className="numbers" key={inHouse.id}>Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)</h2> // this renders multiple times as what is in the length
              <div className="house">
                <h2 key={inHouse.id}>{rep.short_title + " " + rep.first_name + " " + rep.last_name}</h2>
                <ul key={inHouse.id} className="bio">
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>{rep.title}</li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>State: <strong>{rep.state}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>Party: <strong>{rep.party}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>DOB: <strong>{rep.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>Next Election: <strong>{rep.next_election}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>Missed Votes: <strong>{rep.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}> Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                  <li key={inHouse.id}>Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>

    )
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8121x.jpg
```

Comment: you only need keys on the outer most container element in a loop

Comment: @imjared Hi, I've tried doing that and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move repetitive `<h2>` out of `map()` function:

```
return (
  <div className="congress">

    <div className="users">
      <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
      <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>

    {/* inSenate.map() */}

    <h2 className="numbers" key={inHouse.id}>Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)</h2>

    {/* inHouse.map() */}
  </div>
)
```

Try fully working example below:

```js
class Members extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: null,
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    });
  };


  // needed to simplify function code to make it runnable
  // responseData is `members` array (source: https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/members/)
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      represenatives: responseData
    });
  }

  render() {
    const inHouse = this.state.represenatives.filter(
      item => item.state === this.state.userInput
    );
    
    return (
      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <span>Write "TN" or "WY"</span>
        </div>
        <h2 className="numbers">
          Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)
        </h2>
        {inHouse.map((rep, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={inHouse.id} className="houses">
              <div className="house">
                <h2>
                  {rep.short_title + " " + rep.first_name + " " + rep.last_name}
                </h2>
                <ul className="bio">
                  <li>{rep.title}</li>
                  <li>
                    State: <strong>{rep.state}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Party: <strong>{rep.party}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    DOB: <strong>{rep.date_of_birth}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Next Election: <strong>{rep.next_election}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Missed Votes: <strong>{rep.missed_votes}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    {" "}
                    Votes With Party Percentage:{" "}
                    <strong>{rep.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Votes Against Party Percentage:{" "}
                    <strong>{rep.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const responseData = [
        {
          id: "A000360",
          title: "Senator, 2nd Class",
          short_title: "Sen.",
          api_uri:
            "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json",
          first_name: "Lamar",
          middle_name: null,
          last_name: "Alexander",
          suffix: null,
          date_of_birth: "1940-07-03",
          gender: "M",
          party: "R",
          leadership_role: null,
          twitter_account: "SenAlexander",
          facebook_account: "senatorlamaralexander",
          youtube_account: "lamaralexander",
          govtrack_id: "300002",
          cspan_id: "5",
          votesmart_id: "15691",
          icpsr_id: "40304",
          crp_id: "N00009888",
          google_entity_id: "/m/01rbs3",
          fec_candidate_id: "S2TN00058",
          url: "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public",
          rss_url: "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed",
          contact_form:
            "http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email",
          in_office: true,
          cook_pvi: null,
          dw_nominate: 0.324,
          ideal_point: null,
          seniority: "17",
          next_election: "2020",
          total_votes: 374,
          missed_votes: 75,
          total_present: 0,
          last_updated: "2019-12-04 07:18:43 -0500",
          ocd_id: "ocd-division/country:us/state:tn",
          office: "455 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
          phone: "202-224-4944",
          fax: "202-228-3398",
          state: "TN",
          senate_class: "2",
          state_rank: "senior",
          lis_id: "S289",
          missed_votes_pct: 20.05,
          votes_with_party_pct: 96.98,
          votes_against_party_pct: 3.02
        },
        {
          id: "E000285",
          title: "Senator, 2nd Class",
          short_title: "Sen.",
          api_uri:
            "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/E000285.json",
          first_name: "Michael",
          middle_name: "B.",
          last_name: "Enzi",
          suffix: null,
          date_of_birth: "1944-02-01",
          gender: "M",
          party: "R",
          leadership_role: "",
          twitter_account: "SenatorEnzi",
          facebook_account: "mikeenzi",
          youtube_account: "senatorenzi",
          govtrack_id: "300041",
          cspan_id: "45824",
          votesmart_id: "558",
          icpsr_id: "49706",
          crp_id: "N00006249",
          google_entity_id: "/m/021ph1",
          fec_candidate_id: "S6WY00126",
          url: "https://www.enzi.senate.gov",
          rss_url: "https://www.enzi.senate.gov/public/?a=rss.feed",
          contact_form:
            "http://www.enzi.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact?p=e-mail-senator-enzi",
          in_office: true,
          cook_pvi: null,
          dw_nominate: 0.542,
          ideal_point: null,
          seniority: "23",
          next_election: "2020",
          total_votes: 374,
          missed_votes: 2,
          total_present: 0,
          last_updated: "2019-12-03 19:50:32 -0500",
          ocd_id: "ocd-division/country:us/state:wy",
          office: "379a Russell Senate Office Building",
          phone: "202-224-3424",
          fax: "202-228-0359",
          state: "WY",
          senate_class: "2",
          state_rank: "senior",
          lis_id: "S254",
          missed_votes_pct: 0.53,
          votes_with_party_pct: 96.76,
          votes_against_party_pct: 3.24
        },
        {
          id: "B001261",
          title: "Senator, 1st Class",
          short_title: "Sen.",
          api_uri:
            "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B001261.json",
          first_name: "John",
          middle_name: null,
          last_name: "Barrasso",
          suffix: null,
          date_of_birth: "1952-07-21",
          gender: "M",
          party: "R",
          leadership_role: "Senate Republican Conference Chair",
          twitter_account: "SenJohnBarrasso",
          facebook_account: "johnbarrasso",
          youtube_account: "barrassowyo",
          govtrack_id: "412251",
          cspan_id: "1024777",
          votesmart_id: "52662",
          icpsr_id: "40707",
          crp_id: "N00006236",
          google_entity_id: "/m/02rsm32",
          fec_candidate_id: "S6WY00068",
          url: "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov",
          rss_url: "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/?a=rss.feed",
          contact_form:
            "https://www.barrasso.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact-form",
          in_office: true,
          cook_pvi: null,
          dw_nominate: 0.538,
          ideal_point: null,
          seniority: "13",
          next_election: "2024",
          total_votes: 374,
          missed_votes: 0,
          total_present: 0,
          last_updated: "2019-12-03 19:50:32 -0500",
          ocd_id: "ocd-division/country:us/state:wy",
          office: "307 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
          phone: "202-224-6441",
          fax: null,
          state: "WY",
          senate_class: "1",
          state_rank: "junior",
          lis_id: "S317",
          missed_votes_pct: 0.0,
          votes_with_party_pct: 96.77,
          votes_against_party_pct: 3.23
        }
      ];

ReactDOM.render(<Members />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, why do I need to move that h2 out of there?

Comment: `map()` iterates over all `inHouse` members and adds `<h2>Your state has N Represenative(s)</h2>` for each one. Moving it out of `map()` make it render one time.

Comment: So, where am I supposed to put it, if I want it in that div.

Comment: You need it in that `<div>` because of styling? Please, tell me what is your motivation.

Comment: The reason I want it in house div because it returns the number of representatives in that particular state.

Comment: Does moving `<div className="houses">` out of `map ()` could solve a problem? Then inside `map ()` function you would iterate over and create only `<div className="house">` elements.

Comment: I don't think so. I am new to react and everything is confusing right now. Thanks for all your help, though